# Why is there no up to date core data documentation for Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

It used to be so easy to create core data classes. All you would have to do is do file > new file > Managed Object Subclass and BAM! You have your class and you can use it as you'd expect for core data.

Now there's no such option. And no one is wondering where the option is.
I tried making the class manually because the core data property extension is supposed to be in the derived data now because I thought it would just work (this also means you'll always get compile errors because you can't import the necessary headers to make relationships work but that's a whole different kettle of fish)
But of course it doesn't work.

If I made an entity "Person" with attribute "name" I can't make an instance of it and access the attribute "name" even if the class file exists and even if the property extension exists.

Everywhere I've looked there's people asking about how to get their old core data objects to compile from their old projects but no one is making fresh brand new projects.

I've googled things such as
"xcode 8 core data how to create coredata classes"
"xcode 8 what is "manual/none" "class definition" "category/extension""
"xcode 8 what is manual/none class definition"
"xcode 8 make file for core data entity"
"xcode 8 where is the coredata subclass option"
"xcode 8 core data tutorial"

but nothing useful shows up. Everything is related to Xcode versions prior to 8 or has answers/questions from other people only related to the "Tool version"

How do I create core data subclasses in Xcode 8?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH4-SW1. Use this link, don't skip any part. Just try a sample app first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the option in Xcode 8 - Create NSManagedObject Subclass

[image]

Comment: That creates the categories but aren't they meant to be auto generated and kept in derived data?

Comment: It actually creates 4 files: YourEntity.h/.m - theses files can be modified and will not be recreated later, and YourEntity+CoreDataProperties.h/m, which will be created each time you press "Create NSManagedObject Subclass..." button. And no, they are not meant to be kept in derived data. Does it solve you problem?

Comment: There is also a tool for Core Data code generation - https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator

Comment: It does what the old Xcode does, but it takes a lot more post processing after they are created to make them work... An annoying extra overhead but at least there's a way to make this work. Thanks!